# MySQL replication positioning changes

Tags: mysql

I am using the concept of MySQL master master replication for synchronizing the data between two servers.

Now the problem which exists for me is that upon editing some data in any table, the changes get reflected at other end. However master_log_pos changes on every change whenever an update or change in data is done at either end.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems unclear to me because the behavior you are describing is normal.  When the data on a master changes, the master should write those changes to its binlog, whether the change was initiated locally or came in on the replicatiom stream... so the log file positon would normally advance on both machines, if the `log_slave_updates` global variable is turned on at each master.

You could turn it off, but you shouldn't, because then neither server's binlog would have a complete copy of all the changes, regardless of source, severely complicating or even eliminating the possibility of using either server's binlog for point in time recovery.

If you are thinking there's a loop, you're partially correct, because there is.  When "A" sends an event to "B," "B" will execute the event, write it to its binlog, and send that event out to any and all conmected slaves.  When "A" receives its own event back from "B," it realizes that it was the initiator of the event, and discards it.  The originating server breaks the loop.

This is the only way it can work, since every master sends exactly the same binlog events to *all* connected slaves.  If "all" slaves doesn't make sense, recall that in master/master, you can also subtend one or more read-only replica slaves from each master.  If both masters didn't send their incoming replication events back out again to all slaves, then subtended slaves wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thanks. However my master 1 and 2 databases are not in sync after the position changes.

Comment: If you start out with identical data and make identical changes to each copy, the data will be in sync... so, either you are not replicating all data changes, or you didn't start with identical data on both servers... those are the only two possibilities, but you'll need to identify which one is the issue and go from there.

Comment: I started with all the datas in sync. Whenever i make some changes on either database only the master log pos changes and others like binlog file remains the same.